# I can't log into my wordpress site

Tags: login

I can't log into my website https://www.destressxpress.com.au/.
All the suggested answers appear to say to change folders etc within the website, but I can't get in to do that.
It appears that the Bloom plugin has depreciated.
If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be thankful, or should I contact my hosting site
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean your usual login doesn't work any more, or you get an error (from the Bloom plugin?) when you try to log in?

Comment: If you don't have enough access to fix things then you will need to contact your host, yes, especially if it's managed WordPress hosting.

Comment: You probably just need to upgrade your Bloom plugin to make the deprecation warnings go away (and/or turn on WP_DEBUG in your wp-config file to hide the warnings, but I'd do the upgrade). I doubt these would be breaking your login though.

Comment: IF you can access your FTP/SFTP, add an underscore to the from of the Bloom plugin's directory.  This will deactivate it. So assuming the directory is `bloom`, change it to `_bloom`.

Answer (score 1):

Using FTP/ SFTP go to wp-content/plugins/ and change the plugin folder name from "bloom" to "bloom-" it will disable the plugin, and you will be able to use WordPress native login.

Comment: Is this a known issue then, that the Bloom plugin breaks the login flow? The deprecation warnings on the home page look like they're just for the admin dashboard.

Comment: Yes, seems bloom plugin has a dashboard and warning should be displayed on Admin screen :).
FYI: As I checked bloom plugin has closed and last updated 8 years ago (https://wordpress.org/plugins/bloom/).